# Splunk - Trigger HTTP call for every event received at Real Time

Tags: output, real-time, splunk

I have an use case in which for every event/data-input that reaches the Splunk server, certain fields need to be parsed out and a HTTP call triggered with the parsed parameters in the real-time non-window'd mode. What is the appropriate way to achieve that.

Splunk Version used: 6.x

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles into this... Achieved this using Alerts over Scheduled/real-time searches.